# How to show values other than the sample text that's on textView in Android

Tags: java, android, obd-ii

I'm making a OBDII reader app and would like to see the (in this case) voltage on text rather than in the Logcat which is what I currently see. You can see in the code below where I read the voltage in my while loop. Is it possible to update the `textView` everytime the loop runs?

Any help is appreciated!

**.java**

```
public class BTHandler {

    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private String status;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private int pPlatform = Constants.SPA;
    private boolean connectionStatus = false;

    public BTHandler(Context context, Handler handler) { // Konstruktor
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void write(String s) {
        mConnectedThread.sendRawCommand(s);
        Log.v("write", "write");
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
    }

    public void connect(String deviceAddress) {
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(deviceAddress);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    private void guiHandler(int what, int arg1, String obj) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = what;
        msg.obj = obj;
        msg.arg1 = arg1;
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(String deviceAddress) {
            mmDevice = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                }
                guiHandler(Constants.TOAST, Constants.SHORT, "Connection Failed");
                return;
            }
            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            guiHandler(Constants.CONNECTION_STATUS, Constants.STATE_CONNECTED, "");
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();

        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private ObdMultiCommand multiCommand;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            connectionStatus = true;
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;


            switch (pPlatform) {
                case Constants.SPA:
                    multiCommand = new ObdMultiCommand();
                    multiCommand.add(new OdbRawCommand(SPA.VOLTAGE));
                    break;
            }

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("e", "e");
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            OBDcmds();

            ModuleVoltageCommand voltageCommand = new ModuleVoltageCommand();
            //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    voltageCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                    voltageCommand.getFormattedResult();
                    Log.d("Log", "Voltage:" + voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());
                    textView.setText(voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // CALL this to MainActivity
        public void sendRawCommand(String s) {

            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("sendRawCommand", "e");
            }
        }


        /*
        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        */


        private void OBDcmds() { // execute commands

            try {
                new EchoOffCommand().run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                new LineFeedOffCommand().run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                new TimeoutCommand(100).run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.AUTO).run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                //ISO_15765_4_CAN

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("OBDcmds", "e");
                // handle errors
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                connectionStatus = false;
                mmSocket.close();

                guiHandler(Constants.CONNECTION_STATUS, Constants.STATE_NOT_CONNECTED, "");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button b1;
    BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    BTHandler btHandler;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_connected_to, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.v("Log", "Connected");
                            break;
                        case BTHandler.STATE_NONE:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btHandler = new BTHandler(MainActivity.this, mHandler);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.device_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        //String voltage = ("ATRV");

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.connect:
                onConnect(); //Operation
                Log.v("Log", "Pressed onClick");
                break;
            case R.id.getValue:
                btHandler.write(SPA.VOLTAGE);
                Log.v("getValue","" + SPA.VOLTAGE);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.enable_bluetooth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void onConnect() {
        ArrayList deviceStrs = new ArrayList();
        final ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList();

        BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set pairedDevices = mAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (Object device : pairedDevices) {
                BluetoothDevice bdevice = (BluetoothDevice) device;
                deviceStrs.add(bdevice.getName() + "\n" + bdevice.getAddress());
                devices.add(bdevice.getAddress());
            }
        }

        // show list
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice,
                deviceStrs.toArray(new String[deviceStrs.size()]));

        alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                int position = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                String deviceAddress = devices.get(position);

                btHandler.connect(deviceAddress);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setTitle("Paired devices");
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if your question is "is it possible" - then the answer would be "yes it is". Have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object extends the `Thread` so I assume that it would be started like this

```
ConnectedThread ct = new ConnectedThread(socket);
ct.start();
```

In Android you can't update `View` from non-UI thread. You would need to create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and pass the data to it. In you `Handler` implementation you would be able to call the `setText()` method to update your `TextView`.

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) for more details about communication with UT thread.

**For the updated post**

I personally don't like the idea to change the layout of the `Activity` in the `Handler` implementation - I would go for `Fragment`s usage.

Anyway after calling the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected)` in your `Handler` you need to call the `findViewById` again to find the `TextView` in your `activity_connected` layout:

```
case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_connected_to, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v("Log", "Connected");
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText("Connected");
    break;
```

**Code snippet update**

**ConnectedThread#run()**

```
public void run() {
        OBDcmds();

        ModuleVoltageCommand voltageCommand = new ModuleVoltageCommand();
        //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                voltageCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                Log.d("Log", "Voltage:" + voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());
                guiHandler(Constants.VOLTAGE_STATUS, 0, voltageCommand.getFormattedResult())
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Handler implementation**
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        TextView textView = null;

```
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_connected_to, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.v("Log", "Connected");
                        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        break;
                    case BTHandler.STATE_NONE:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Constants.VOLTAGE_STATUS:
                if(msg.obj != null && textView != null){
                    textView.setText((String)msg.obj)
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah! I forgot to mention that (that's a non-UI thread). I do have a handler in Main. Check the edited OP

Comment: Post your `Activity#onCreate` method implementation

Comment: Okay! Thanks. Right now it shows "Connected" instead of the voltage. And when I try to write `tv.setText(voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());` it can't resolve the symbol. Maybe i'm doing something wrong here :/

Comment: Yes, since it handles the `STATE_CONNECTED` event. You need to pass your voltage value to the `Handler` like this: `msg.obj = voltageCommand.getFormattedResult()` in your `ConnectedThread#run()` method

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry if i'm being a bit difficult here, but should the `msg.obj...` go in the while loop in ConnectedThread run. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/DpbnWyJ.png

Comment: Tried it, now it shows the sample text "Medium Text". Should the int for VOLTAGE_STATUS be anything in particular? I have set it to `int VOLTAGE_STATUS = 6;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109423/discussion-between-victornlj-and-swess).

Answer (score 0):

Use `textView.setText(voltageCommand.getFormattedResult())`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to map your textView to the resource ID.

```
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

you can place the above line after setContentView("your layout");

Now, you can use this textView and set the data as shown below,

```
textView.setText(voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());
```

Comment: I don't have `setContentView("layout");` in that class. Forgot to mention that. This class just handles all the Bluetooth stuff. When I put `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);` under `onCreate` in `MainActivity` and `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);` in the other class (BTHandler) I get the error `Cannot resolve method 'findViewById (int)'`

Answer (score 0):

This is about Android app development basics, you should read the tutorials at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

You can access the TextView with
 `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.textView)`;.

Then change your text with

```
textView.setText("new message");
```

HTH